# New Component is returned but the previous component stays the same in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

A new component is returned after login, but both the login component and the Home Component are seen on the page. I need to return the Home Componenet without Login Component. I am new to React and still trying to understand return and routes in React.

This is my pages component which returns either Login or Home based on this.state.redirect1.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
    import '../../App.css';
    import Login from '../Login';
    import Home from '../Home';
    import Header from './Header';
    import Footer from './Footer';


    class Pages extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
          redirect: false,
        }

  }
  handleClick() {
    this.state.redirect = true;
    console.log(this.state.redirect);
  }
  changeRedirect =() =>{
    this.state.redirect = true;
    console.log(this.state.redirect);
    this.forceUpdate()

  }
  renderRedirect = () => {
    if(this.props.redirect1){
      return <Home/>
    }
    else{
      return <Login/>
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (

      <div className="mh-100 PgWidth">
      {this.renderRedirect()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Pages
```

Below is my Login, Home and App Components

```
Login.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios';
import Pages from './common/Pages'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class Login extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            redirect: false
        }
    }

    handleUsername = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            username: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handlePassword = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            password: event.target.value
        })
    }
    renderRedirect = () => {
        if (this.state.redirect) {
            console.log("from render redirect");
            return <Pages redirect1={this.state.redirect} />
        }
    }


    formSubmitHandler = event => {
        let formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("username", this.state.username);
        formdata.append("password", this.state.password);
        Axios.post("/auth/local",{
            "name":this.state.username,
            "password": this.state.password
           })
            .then(res => {
                if (res) {
                    console.log(res);
                    this.setState({ redirect: true });


                }


            })
        event.preventDefault() // used to keep the form data as entered even after the submit
    }

    render() {

        const { username, password } = this.state
        return (

            <div className="p-5">
            { this.renderRedirect() }
                <h3>Sign-In</h3>
                <form onSubmit={this.formSubmitHandler}>
                    <div className="form-group row">
                        <label htmlFor="inputEmail3" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Username</label>
                        <div className="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" value={username} onChange={this.handleUsername}
                                className="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Username" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group row">
                        <label htmlFor="inputPassword3" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
                        <div className="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="password" value={password} onChange={this.handlePassword}
                                className="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group row">
                        <div className="col-sm-2">Checkbox</div>
                        <div className="col-sm-10">
                            <div className="form-check">
                                <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck1" />
                                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="gridCheck1">
                                    Example checkbox
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group row">
                        <div className="col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" onClick={this.formSubmitHandler} className="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Login
```

Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../App.css';


export class Home extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log("home component mount");
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>The page has been routed</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/common/Header';
import Footer from './components/common/Footer';
import Pages from './components/common/Pages';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <div className="App container-fluid bg-light w-75">
      <div className="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div className="col m-0 p-0">
          <Header/>
            <div className="">
            <Pages/>
            </div>
          <Footer/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: [This](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) might help.

Comment: But if I use Redirect I will not be getting Header or Footer Component as it will redirect to Home Component which has no footers or Headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is in this line:

```
{ this.renderRedirect() }
```

Once redirect will be true, it will render the Home page first then the Login component.

Solution to you problem is: Manage the redirect bool in Page component only, and pass a function to update to Login component to update its value and decide the component based on that.

Changes:

1- defined `redirect: false` in Pages component.

2- A function to change its value in Pages component:

```
updateValue = (value) => {
  this.setState({ redirect: true })
}
```

3- Pass function to Login component:

```
renderRedirect = () => {
  if(this.props.redirect1) {
    return <Home/>
  }
  else{
    // =====> here
    return <Login updateValue={this.updateValue} />
  }
}
```

4- After successful Login call this function and render Home Component:

```
formSubmitHandler = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  let formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("username", this.state.username);
  formdata.append("password", this.state.password);

  Axios.post("/auth/local",{
    "name":this.state.username,
    "password": this.state.password
  })
  .then(res => {
    if (res) {
       // =======> here
       this.props.updateValue(true)
    }
  })
}
```

5- Remove this line from Login Component:

```
{ this.renderRedirect() }
```

**Problem with current code:**

You are managing the login session using state variable, so after refreshing the page it will again show the login page not home page. So better to store the value in `localStorage` and read its value in page component to decide the initial value of `redirect`.

**Suggestion:**

Instead of deciding the route/component using `boolean`, better to use [**react-router**](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) for better structuring/managing the app.

Comment: Thank you, also I have added this.forceUpdate() in the updateValue(value) in the end,

Comment: I think without that it should work. Is it not working without forceUpdate?

Comment: No, its not. The value of redirect is changing to 'true', but the component did not render.

Answer (score 1):

Try return it in render:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
    import '../../App.css';
    import Login from '../Login';
    import Home from '../Home';
    import Header from './Header';
    import Footer from './Footer';


    class Pages extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
          redirect: false,
        }

  }
  handleClick() {
    this.state.redirect = true;
    console.log(this.state.redirect);
  }
  changeRedirect =() =>{
    this.state.redirect = true;
    console.log(this.state.redirect);
    this.forceUpdate()

  }

  render() {

  if(this.props.redirect){
    return (
      <div className="mh-100 PgWidth">
        <Home/>
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="mh-100 PgWidth">
        <Login/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Pages;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is resulting the same Issue.

Comment: Hmm, okay what now?

Comment: I think You have a typo. I didn't find `redirect1` in Your code

Comment: redirect1 is a prop from Login Component. Sorry for that

Comment: Yes but You don't define it somewhere. For first You must define `direct1` in Pages as State and only after that use it in other pages as props

Comment: Just try to change state `redirect1` into `redirect` in Your Pages.js , see what will be

Comment: Since the initial value of redirect1 is undefined, it will not make any difference. I have created a prop as return <Pages redirect1={this.state.redirect} /> in Login Component.

Comment: Oh, I'm happy that You got the answer, very interesting question :)

Comment: Thank you @Robert. You can upvote it if you want :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
<div className="mh-100 PgWidth">
  {this.props.redirect1&&<Home/>}
  {!this.props.redirect1&&<Login />}
</div>
```

But, the best way to do this is using react router and managing the global react state